# Writing a string to a file in Python 3.6.8 with raw escaped characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a string to disk in Python 3.6.8 using the built-in write function. The issue is that the string I'm trying to write has escaped characters in it that I need to maintain. ie I want the string ***"hello\n\tworld"*** to be ***"hello\n\tworld"*** when written to disk and *not*:

```
hello
     world
```

***Example Code:***

```
example_text = '''
hello
world
hello\n\tworld
'''

with open('example.txt', 'w') as example_file:
    example_file.write(example_text)
    example_file.close()
```

***Output:***

```
hello
world
hello
    world
```

The only thing that seems to work is replacing the backslashes with double backslashes, however I'm having a difficult time doing this in code, string.replace doesn't quite work in any way I've tried.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but: you don't have to call `example_file.close()` because the `with` statement will close the file for you. This is the primary reason for using a `with` statement on a file in the first place.

Comment: The fundamental idea you are missing here is that escaped characters *don't exist in the string*. They are used in *source code* to represent certain characters, like newlines, or in the printed *representation* of a string object. IOW, a string literal `'\n'` is a string of length *exactly 1*, not 2, with the newline character in it, not a backslash and an n. Which is why `.replace` won't work, *because there are no backslashes in your string*. What is the source of your strings? Are you just writing them out in source code? Why must they maintain escape sequences?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the insights! This helped me consider other sources where the problem might be occurring from, and I was able to fix it. I was getting the strings from a GET request upstream, and was able to confirm that it was a string literal there. Further downstream, I was replacing the string in a larger body using the re.sub function, and this was causing the issue. The reason I needed to maintain the escape sequences is because the final output is some dynamically generated code.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks! That's good to know, I'm still somewhat new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [raw `r`-prefix](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) before each string-literal:

```
example_text = r'''
hello
world
hello\n\tworld
'''

with open('example.txt', 'w') as example_file:
    example_file.write(example_text)
    example_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my example, unfortunately the problem was happening further upstream and the string was being stored in a variable, and therefore the issue wasn't resolved. After further investigation it seems that using the regex function re.sub was causing the raw escaped characters to change. I instead used the string's replace function with success :-)